# DocuSign double login

Tags: authentication, docusignapi

Our DocusSgn integration is currently a two step process:

1. the user clicks on "Login to DocuSign" whereupon they are redirected to "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&state=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&prompt=login&redirect_uri=www.stackoverflow.com/app/callback" (for example) where they login, so that we can get an authentication.
2. we have the templates populated from DocuSign using the authentication. The user selects the template and clicks "Go to DocuSign" where upon a popup takes them to "https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents/details/c921ac4b-fdae-48a9-a70e-5d8a4e3e0089" for example.

The problem is that the user is forced to login both times. The expectation is that after the initial login during step 1, the user would not need to login again in step 2 since the domain names match (and DocuSign would create session cookies for the login).

Is there any way/process that we can follow which would allow us to not have to do this awkward double login?

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Login is the OAUTH login in which user is giving your IntegratorKey (Client_Id) access to call DS ESign APIs and impersonate user on the user's behalf. Using this flow you will never get access to bypass DS Weblogin page to access the page hosted by DocuSign like the one which you have - `https://appdemo.docusign.com/documents/details/c921ac4b-fdae-48a9-a70e-5d8a4e3e0089`. If you want to give access to the user to edit the templates using API then you need to use below API call with the OAUTH Access token:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/views/edit
```

Documentation for the same is available at:
[TemplateViews: createEdit](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateViews/createEdit/)

Comment: cool. Awesome! tried the https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/ endpoint to create a url to the envelope with a temporary login. And it works!